# How would you find the XOR of all integers in the range l to r, where -(10^18) <= l,r <= 10^18?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I know that this is how you would implement it when the 1 <= l,r <= 10^18, but how would you deal with the negative number?

```
long long int xorf(long long int n){
    long long int mod=n%4;
    switch(mod){
        case 0:return n;
            break;
        case 1:return 1;
            break;
        case 2:return n+1;
            break;
        case 3:return 0;
            break;
    }
    int main(){
    long long int l,r;
    long long int xo=0;
        cin>>l>>r;
        xo = (xorf(l-1)^xorf(r));
        cout<<xo<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: Well it depends on how you represent negative numbers.

Comment: what do you mean? @RichardCritten

Comment: What is (-1) XOR (-2) and why?

Comment: @Somebodyoncetoldme 3 typical choices: 2s complement, 1s complement, sign and magnitude.

Comment: @Evg (Assuming) XOR (in C++ the operator `^`) is a bitwise operation. -1 and -2 have a bit representation. Applying XOR yields a new bit pattern which again can be interpreted as integer. The result depends on how negative numbers are mapped to bit patterns. Nowadays, C++ compilers and platforms often (mostly?) supports [2 complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). That would result in: [-1 ^ -2: 1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/919ce99f695fe749)

Comment: @Scheff, since C++20, signed integers will be 2's complement by the standard.

Comment: @Scheff: "often (mostly?)": how about "exclusively"?

Comment: @Scheff I'm supposed to be writing a solution for C++14

Comment: _I'm supposed to be writing a solution for C++14_ Don't worry. That will even work with [`-std=c++11`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01a8bc4c9e1e3066). (I just used the default setting.)

Comment: @TonyK May be, I'm under the impression of exotic counter examples for platforms I read from time to time in SO. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If n >= 0, then (as you say) `1 ^ 2 ^ ... ^ n` can be computed by:

```
long long PositiveXor(long long n){
  switch (n % 4){
        case 0: return n ;
        case 1: return 1 ;
        case 2: return n+1 ;
        case 3: return 0 ;
    }
}
```

Similarly, if `n < 0`, then `n ^ (n+1) ^ ... ^ -1` can be computed by:

```
long long NegativeXor(long long n){
  switch ((-n) % 4){
        case 0: return 0 ;
        case 1: return n ;
        case 2: return 1 ;
        case 3: return n-1 ;
    }
}
```

(This assumes 2's complement representation.)

So if `l >= 0`, the answer is `PositiveXor(r) ^ PositiveXor(l-1)`; and if `l < 0` and `r >= 0`, the answer is `NegativeXor(l) ^ PositiveXor(r)`. I'll leave the third case (`r < 0`) up to you.